# does data transfer in copper media really just happen by changing voltage?

Tags: ethernet, cable, gigabit-ethernet

As I understand this graphic:

[image]

1 is represented by a voltage of 3 and 0 by a voltage of 0.

As I can imagine, only one voltage is possible at a time on a cable (So you cannot have 2 voltage and 3 voltage at the same time on the same medium right).

Does the voltage change in a cable which for instance transmits 1 Gbit/s really 1 billion times?
And how close is the above graphic to todays copper-cables (twister-pair)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the voltage change in a cable which for instance transmits 1 Gbit/s really 1 billion times?

## In general, yes.

It's slightly more complex in reality, but not too much. If you have multiple wires available, you can use them to send multiple signals at the same time (increasing throughput or decreasing frequency).

You can also use them to reduce interference - if you have a twisted pair, you can send real signal through one wire and inverted signal through the other. Then you invert the second wire once again at the receiving end and sum it with original one - interferences will cancel out.

Additional encoding is also used, for example 8-bit values can be transmitted using 10-bit codes. This reduces throughput, but allows for error detection/correction. The codes are also designed in such a way that you can use them for clock synchronization.

Comment: And how does one know the time between two downs (zeros) to really realize that there are "two downs (zeros)"? (If you know what I mean).

Comment: @watchme: Either counting them based on a clock signal, or by encoding the bits in such a way that there _aren't_ two successive zeros (e.g. originally Ethernet used [Manchester code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code)).

Answer (score 4):

> does data transfer in copper media really just happen by changing voltage?

Depends on the modulation used to transmit the information.

"Changing voltage" is properly called amplitude modulation.
Information can also be transmitted using frequency modulation, phase modulation, or some combination.

TTL uses amplitude modulation.  But TTL is almost exclusively used for on-board logic connections, and rarely used for communications or distances longer than a few feet or half meter.  (The Centronics printer interface, or IEEE 1284, is a rare exception.)

> As I understand this graphic:
>    ...
>   1 is represented by a voltage of 3 and 0 by a voltage of 0.

You're looking at an idealized waveform for TTL. In reality those nice square waves can actually look quite ragged in real life. 
[image]

> As I can imagine, only one voltage is possible at a time on a cable (So you cannot have 2 voltage and 3 voltage at the same time on the same medium right).

Instantaneously there is a single voltage value on the wire, but it could be the sum of one or more signal voltages, because it depends on the modulation and the signal(s) exists in an analog world.
That "digital" signal is so-called because the information is digital, i.e. quantized to two states.
But such "digital" signals have to exist in the analog world.  That means that signal levels are part of a continuous waveform and cannot exist precisely at only two levels.

For TTL those two "levels" are actually two voltage ranges, an upper voltage range (e.g. 2.4V to 3.3V for 3.3V logic) for the high state and a lower voltage range (e.g. 0V to 0.4V for 3.3V logic) for the low state.

> Does the voltage change in a cable which for instance transmits 1 Gbit/s really 1 billion times?

Again that depends on the modulation.
For TTL that would be true.  But communication signals rarely use TTL because of bandwidth requirements and signal integrity.

Ethernet typically uses PAM, pulse amplitude modulation.  For instance two (2) bits could be encoded per pulse using four voltage levels.  So only a half billion voltage changes would be required in your example.

Digital television can use QAM256, quadrature amplitude modulation, which employs phase and amplitude.  Eight bits can be encoded per symbol.

Rather than *"voltage changes"* (which implies only discrete levels are required) the communication metric used is bandwidth, which is expressed as the frequency of a sinusoidal wave.  Fourier analysis would tell you that the square wave depicted in your question requires an infinitely-high bandwidth medium.
(Note that the photo above is of a high-bandwidth, 10 giga-sample/sec digital scope.)

> And how close is the above graphic to todays copper-cables (twister-pair)?

You could never capture such perfect waveforms in real life with an oscilloscope; they don't exist.
And its label of *"pure digital signal"* is bogus, since it shows transitions between levels.  A true "digital signal" would not be continuous, but rather only have discontinuous states.

Comment: What does TTL stands for?

Comment: @Jon -- Transistor-Transistor Logic.  Suggest you learn how to use a search engine.

Answer (score 3):

Let's clear something more - although not related to Ethernet itself, but how this is done in general "in copper" (and "in the air" as well).

> As I can imagine, only one voltage is possible at a time on a cable
>   (So you cannot have 2 voltage and 3 voltage at the same time on the
>   same medium right).

Actually, you can as many "voltages" in a cable as you want (only limited by conductor bandwidth and quality of transmitter/receiver equipment). In order to acomplish this you simply feed it with multiple orthogonal frequencies. Of course this will produce single "voltage" output (with weird waveform), but they are re-separatable at the other end.

> Does the voltage change in a cable which for instance transmits 1
>   Gbit/s really 1 billion times?

In case of frequency/phase-modulated signals (FM/PM) the actual voltage change is many times faster than the resulting digital bitrate itself. For example, in DVB-C television signal the net bitrate is about 50 Mb/s (per 8 MHz channel), while the carrier frequency is anything between 100 MHz and 1 GHz. With QAM256 modulation one symbol encodes 8 bits, so 50 Mb/s generates about 6250 kS/s (6.25 million of symbols per second). This means that one symbol is transmitted during 160 ns (in reality this is more complicated, but let's keep this simple). 6.25 MS/s transmitted using 100-1000 MHz carrier. There are about 100 separate channels of 8 MHz width within allowed band, so you can send about 5 Gb/s over coaxial cable, while all the "voltages" are changing ca. 50 billion (short scale) times per second (estimated as: 500 MHz mean carrier frequency multiplied by 100 channels).

With DVB-T schema this is even more complicated, as each channel contains ~2000 or ~8000 subcarriers (COFDM), so the actual "voltages" change their value 20000~80000 faster than the actual bitrate.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've asked about Gigabit Ethernet over copper - 1000BASE-T specifically:

1000BASE-T uses all four twisted pairs simultaneously in both directions. The gigabit data stream is separated into four lanes of 250 Mbit/s each. A somewhat sophisticated encoding (four-dimensional trellis code modulation) with PAM-5 (5 different voltage levels) brings the symbol rate to 125 MBaud - this is the same as 100BASE-TX, thus the same Cat-5e cabling requirements, but each lane transports 2.5x the information content.